# findByID() id returning null value

Tags: node.js, mongoose

schema definition:

```
const coursesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    author: String,
    tags: [String],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    isPublished: Boolean
});
const Courses = mongoose.model('Courses', coursesSchema);
```

here I connected to database schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo-exercises').then(() => {
    console.log('mongoose connceted successfylly');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('mongoose didnt connected');
})
```

I'm Trying to fetch the records from the MongoDB. But it is returning a null value instead of object

```
async function getCourses() {
  const course = await Courses.find();
  console.log(course);
}
```

it is working well , it is returning all the objects from the database.

```
async function updateCourse(id) {
  const course = await Courses.findById({_id:id});
  console.log(course);
}
```

**edit:**

here I'm passing ID to fetch the ID

```
updateCourse('5a68fe2142ae6a6482c4c9cb');
```

[image: you can check my database structure]
even I'm passing correct ID

Can any one help me to solve the issue

Comment: should probably be `findById({ id })` or `{ _id: id }` (if you're referring to id created by mongodb)

Comment: And the document you are trying to match and the `id` value you are passing are...? What exactly. You need to include enough information in a question in order for it to be **reproducible**. You should probably also include "schema" if you defined anything for `_id` within that.

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar No it is not.

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar, I tried with your solution but it is not returning any value

Comment: @NeilLunn, yeah I tried with exact ID which is in the scheme

Comment: Asking you to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55439077/edit) and show those details in the question content rather than just telling us you did things. Give us a document to try ourselves that you are having trouble retrieving. Include the schema defined as well for reference.

Comment: As per @NeilLunn suggestion. I edited, please check it once

Comment: And which `_id` are you trying to retrieve in your code? And where is the defined mongoose `Schema` for `Course`? I also suggest you find out how to return the document as "text". Screenshots of code and things that are clearly text are really not welcome here. To be perfectly clear there is nothing wrong with API, which has millions of users worldwide. The only problem is with what **you** are doing, and that problem is not being represented in the information present in the question. Show the `id` value being sent to the function. Show where the value is coming from and it is what you expect

Comment: @change need have you set up mongoose to use `Promise`? else the docs mentions: `await MyModel.findOne({}).exec() if you're using async/await` (note the exec())

Comment: @NeilLunn I edited again see it. I'm just practicing mongodb to learn , Here i'm just console the results

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`findById` documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById), you need to pass only the id as a parameter, instead of the object matching the id (`{_id:id}`).

Your method should be like this:

```
async function updateCourse(id) {
   const course = await Courses.findById(id);
   console.log(course);
}
```